# How to get cell value from specific column/row in a FireMonkey TGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, tgrid

Im trying to get value from specific cell from my TGrid but without success. I have try something like this

```
//Here i get value with a success but i need to get value from first column and 
  no matter what row it is clicked 

TForm1.Grid1GetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol,ARow: Integer; var Value: TValue);  
begin
             if grid1.Selected <> -1 then
                x:= Value.ToString
end;
```

For example i clicked on third row.. i need value from first column third row cell. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.OnGetValue) for the `OnGetValue` event, it says:

> **Occurs when the grid needs to retrieve a value from an external repository** to use as the content of one of the cells in this grid.
>
> Write an OnGetValue event handler to **take specific actions when you retrieve a value from an external repository** to use as the content of one of the cells in this grid.

This is when you are using the grid in a virtual-type mode, storing your data outside of the grid (in an array, a database, etc). `TGrid` by itself does not store any data.  You would use the provided `ACol` and `ARow` values to access your own data storage as needed.

If you want to store data in the grid itself, use a [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid) instead, which has a [`Cells`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid.Cells) property for storing strings.